# Method Range of Object Global Failed when assigning named range

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched for about an hour but found nothing that solves my problem. The following code

```
Dim q3ZFj1 As Range
Dim q4ZFj1 As Range
Dim q3ZFj2 As Range
Dim q4ZFj2 As Range

Dim q3Uebj1 As Range
Dim q4Uebj1 As Range
Dim q3Uebj2 As Range
Dim q4Uebj2 As Range

Dim cRow As Long
Dim cCol As Long

Dim startYear As Integer       
Dim nextYear As Integer        

Dim q3j1Name As Variant
Dim q4j1Name As String
Dim q3j2Name As String
Dim q4j2Name As String

Dim c As Variant

For i = 3 + 1 To Sheets.Count

Set q3ZFj1 = Worksheets(i).Range("C501:I512")
Set q4ZFj1 = Worksheets(i).Range("C521:I532")
Set q3ZFj2 = Worksheets(i).Range("C601:I612")
Set q4ZFj2 = Worksheets(i).Range("C621:I632")

startYear = q3ZFj1.Cells(-1, 0)
nextYear = startYear + 1

q3j1Name = "Q3_" & startYear
q4j1Name = "Q4_" & startYear
q3j2Name = "Q3_" & nextYear
q4j2Name = "Q4_" & nextYear

Set q3Uebj1 = Range(q3j1Name)
Set q4Uebj1 = Range("Q4_" & startYear)
Set q3Uebj2 = Range("Q3_" & nextYear)
Set q4Uebj2 = Range("Q4_" & nextYear)
```

Runs fine when stepping through with F8, but when running, I get the Error mentioned in the Title.

It doesn't matter whether I refer to the range using `Range(q3j1Name)` or `Range("Q3_" & startYear)` or if the Variable for `q3j1Name` is declared as String or Variant.

The strings `q3j1Name`, etc. initialize fine, `q3j1Name` to `"Q3_2012"` for example. `Set q3Uebj1 = Range("Q3_2013")` works just fine.

The named ranges exist, but in a different worksheet. `Set q3Uebj1 = Worksheets(2).Range(q3j1Name)` doesn't work either.

Does anybody have a suggestion how I can either fix this or workaround it?

Basically each worksheet being stepped through contains a year value, based on which a range in worksheet2 is used.

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Set q3Uebj1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets(2).Range(q3j1Name)
```

Also, make sure that you are referencing the sheet number correctly.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I added a few more breakpoints and determined that it runs fine through the first sheet, but not the second. The problem ist that the cell which is referenced for startYear is empty in the second sheet. I probably can't hurt to add the reference to the workbook and worksheet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yeah, i was about to add to check the value of this line `startYear = q3ZFj1.Cells(-1, 0)` since it may be the cause of error as well. glad it helps.